# Twitter auto-tweet not showing title

Tags: bug, status-completed, twitter

I just saw a StackExchange tweet that had its title missing.

[image: Tweet Missing Title]

(They seem to have deleted it.)

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: @mmyers It was really just a bug report...no question here.

Comment: Yeah. I was just curious about the SO question, since it looked like a 4-digit ID and it seems unlikely for a question that old to be tweeted. But 7875 is an answer of Shog9's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Woooops. Tweet deleted; bug fixed.